When using Playwright, how can I determine if a button exists on a page?
I am navigating a site where buttons show up on a page depending on the user's input and other factors not known to me. I know every button's class and id and the text it displays. How can I check if a particular button has shown up on the page? Here is what I have done so far but it is not navigating as expected:
    import { chromium } from 'playwright';

      async function main() {
      const browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 50
       });

      // Create a new Playwright context to isolate browsing session
      const context = await browser.newContext();

      // Open a new page/tab within the context
      const page = await context.newPage();

      await page.goto(myLink);    //myLink is entered programatically

      if(await page.locator("button#id1").isVisible()) {
       await page.locator("button#id1").click();
      }
     else if(await page.locator("button#id2").isVisible()) {
       await page.locator("button#id2").click();
     }
   }

Even when the page has a button with id2, it ends up in the first if statement and the button with id1 is not clicked....because it doesn't exist!
I am using the .isVisible() method of the locator function to determine the existence of a button but it is not giving me the result I expected.

This question is similar to: How to check if an element exists on the page in Playwright.js. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please share your site. .click() already waits for actionability, so the isVisible() conditions are unnecessary. You almost never need ifs in Playwright.
